# Script con Autocompletado personalizado en Bash

Tags: bash, shell, shell-script

Basicamente tengo un script que me permite acceder a logs de varios servicios ubicados en diferentes hosts. 
El script recibe como parametro el host y el nombre del servicio que se desea consultar, mas o menos asi:

```
$ consultar-log.sh host nombre_servicio
```

Sin embargo, necesito que el script tenga auto completado, es decir si por ejemplo tengo un servicio que se llama inventario, que al momento de ingresar inv y presione la tecla tab me auto complete las palabaras.

Answer (score 0):

Lo que necesitas son los comandos `complete` y `compgen`.

Primero crea una función que se va a encargar de autocompletar, luego la asocias a un nombre de archivo.

Asegura que la ruta exista, por ejemplo, si es `consultar-log.sh` entonces recuerda poner el punto "." en `./consultar-log.sh` o la ruta completa, etc.

En este caso haré una funcion `_completar1()` para un script de nombre `completar1`:

```
_completar1() {

    local cur prev
    COMPREPLY=()
    cur="${COMP_WORDS[COMP_CWORD]}"
    prev="${COMP_WORDS[COMP_CWORD-1]}"

    servicios="inventario servicio2 servicio3" # Aqui puedes poner los sevicios que tienes.

    case "$cur" in
        --*)
            opts='--help --verbose --version --host -h'  # Aqui hay un ejemplo de opciones
            COMPREPLY=( $(compgen -W "$opts" -- "${cur}") )
            return 0
        ;;
        op1*) # Ejemplo de otra opcion.
            opts='op11 op12 op13'
            COMPREPLY=( $(compgen -W "$opts" -- "${cur}") )
            return 0
        ;;
    esac

    case "$prev" in
        archivos ) # Ejemplo que lista los archivos pdf del directorio actual.
            archivos="$(\ls ./*.pdf)"
            COMPREPLY=( $(compgen -W "$archivos" "${cur}") )
            return 0
        ;;
        #
        # Aqui esta algo que puedes necesitar. 
        # Autocompletar los hosts.
        #
        --host | -h)
            hosts="host1 computadora3 servidor4 11.11.11.11 22.22.22.22"
            #^^^ Serian tus host, aunque tambien los podrias
            #    poner dentro de un array y luego guardarlos en
            #    esta variable como una linea de texto.
            COMPREPLY=( $(compgen -W "${hosts}" -- "${cur}") )
            return 0
        ;;
        *)
        ;;
    esac

    COMPREPLY=( $(compgen -W "${servicios}" -- "${cur}") ) # Aqui solo muesta la variable de
                                                           # servicios.
    return 0
}

#Ahora instalo la funcion _completar1() al archivo "./completar1"
complete -F _completar1 -o filenames ./completar1  # completar1 es el script al que 
#                ^                        ^          va dirigido el auto completado.
#                |                        |_______   En este caso sería tu archivo
#                |                                   consultar-log.sh
#                |
#          _completar1 es la funcion de autocompletado
#          que acabas se acaba de crear.
```

El nombre de "_completar1" (con guión bajo) es así para que se note que es una función especial.
Esta función la puedes poner dentro de un archivo, junto con la instrucción de `complete`, y luego darle `source` a ese archivo.

Un ejemplo funcional es este:

```
$ ./completar1 <TAB> # incluso solo con inv<TAB> te autocompleta a "inventario"
inventario  servicio2   servicio3
$ ./completar1 inventario --host <TAB>
11.11.11.11  22.22.22.22  computadora3       host1        servidor4
$ ./completar1 inventario --host 11.11.11.11 archivos <TAB> ./
a.pdf  b.pdf  c.pdf  d.pdf  e.pdf  f.pdf
```

Encontrarás información muy interesante en:

- [Documentación oficial.](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Programmable-Completion)
- [Ejemplo útil.](https://debian-administration.org/article/317/An_introduction_to_bash_completion_part_2)
- [Un poco más de información.](https://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/tabexpansion.html)
- [Un ejemplo muy completo y algo más complejo.](https://blog.heckel.xyz/2015/03/24/bash-completion-with-sub-commands-and-dynamic-options/)